# non-const elements initializer_list class

Tags: c++, initializer-list

I want to have initializer_list as a parameter in my function in order to use an undetermined amount of a specific type of variable. It must be a initializer_list because I want to be able to create the list on the function call and because I pass the list into other subfunctions. However, I need to be able to modify the elements in the list and I can't because initializer_list automaticly makes the pointers of type const.

So my question is how do I go about making my own initializer_list class? Making a copy of the header with const removed didn't work and I can't seem to find the answer anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. `std::initializer_list` is a magic type that is intricately tied to the compiler, and there is no way to create your own type with the same ability to be constructed from a braced-init-list.

In that sense it's a bit like `std::typeinfo` and `std::nullptr_t`. They happen to be defined in namespace `std` and so appear to be part of the standard library, but they are actually predefined types that are part of the run-time environment and cannot be emulated in pure C++.

Comment: Don't modify them. Or copy the elements into a container, modify the copies, and pass the container on to the other functions.

Answer (score 3):

I think you might be able to just use a vector.

```
void foo(std::vector<int> values);
```

is callable with

```
foo({ 1, 2, 3, 4 });
```

and then you can pass (move) the vector around as usual and the elements are modifyable of course.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this directly. However, I did kind of workaround in my code sometime ago.
First, a `slice` type which is a non-owning wrapper around contiguous chunk of memory - a pointer to its start and its size.
Second, I added following ctor:

```
slice(std::initializer_list<T> && list)
    : slice((T*)list.begin(), list.size())
{ }
```

where T is slice's type. This works well on G++ 4.8 and 4.9, though I didn't check it on 5.X versions.

This is definitely a hack, but you'll be able to use `slice<T>` as function argument, and then (with enough variety of implicit constructors) pass any contiguous container there, including `array`, `vector` and `initializer_list`. With full support for moves.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This just obfuscates a `const_cast` by a C-style cast.